# WPF ComboBox DataBound Event?

Tags: wpf, binding

I use ComboBox.ItemsSource=[some data collection] to bind data to the control.

I want to hookup an event handler to the combobox so that whenever its data updated (or first time bound), I can do somthing.

The problem is I can't find an appropriate event for it. The close guess is DataContextChanged. But that is not invoked when the items get bound/created.

Many thanks in advance for any helps.

Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBox.Items` property is of type `ItemCollection`, which has `CollectionChanged`, `CurrentChanged`, `CurrentChanging` events. They should suit your needs.

[ItemCollection Class MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx)